# Hit "RuntimePermission createClassLoader" while running java version of nachos

Tags: java, permissions, nachos

I tried to run the java version of [Nachos](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/fa10/Nachos/nachos-java.tar.gz) on Windows 7 and Redhat Linux, but both failed due to RuntimePermission problem as below.

```
user\nachos\proj1> java nachos.machine.Machine nachos.conf

 nachos 5.0j initializing... config interrupt timer user-check

 Lacked permission: (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)

Exception in thread "main" nachos.machine.AssertionFailureError
                at nachos.machine.Lib.assertTrue(Lib.java:77)
                at nachos.machine.Lib.assertNotReached(Lib.java:96)
                at nachos.machine.Lib.checkMethod(Lib.java:565)
                at nachos.machine.Machine.checkUserClasses(Machine.java:262)
                at nachos.machine.Machine.main(Machine.java:57)
```

Searching on Google using keywords `RuntimePermission` and `createClassLoader`, found some solutions that need to modify the file: `$(JAVA HOME)\jre\lib\security\java.policy`. So I appended following lines to it.

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

However, it still can't work. Can anyone provide any clues on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Two days passed, but still no person answer my question. Seems few people are interested with Nachos and Java here. Sigh ...

Comment: hello any luck with your problem? I just hit that problem today... looking for an answer myself.

Comment: Yes, luck enough, problem resolved. Solution is very simple. At nachos.machine.Machine.checkUserClasses(Machine.java:259), comment this line: // checkUserClasses();

Comment: Thanks.... But doesn't it cause any other problems?

Comment: @Buddha Til now, it works fine.